# Does the tradition of Sabbath originate from the Babylonian rest day Sapattu?

Tags: religion

It is often claimed that the tradition of Sabbath has its origin in ancient Babylon.

The Babylonian restdays are named 'Sapattu' and there are several other similarities (including the linkage to the lunar phases)

So, does the tradition of **Sabbath** really originate from the Babylonian restday **Sapattu** ?

Comment: **"It is often claimed"** This is the first I have heard of it. Do you have a link that backs up the claim that this is often claimed? ;)

Comment: see i.e. this: http://www.sabbathtruth.com/free-resources/article-library/id/912/which-day-of-the-week

Comment: Are there *any* ancient calendars that aren't Lunar based?

Comment: @ralfhtp okay, that's one site, and to be honest, still a rather niche site.  Isn't there some more notable claims being made?

Comment: The related Wikipedia article is filled with "citation needed". for whatever reasons.  It mentions this in relation to an **Assyrian** calendar, which isn't the same thing.

Comment: According to some old testament prophets, failing to observe the Sabbath was the reason for the Babylonian captivity (implying it existed before the Israelites lived there). However, intermingling of traditions could have brought them the _notion_ of Sapattu which they then adapted for their own religion.

Comment: Here is a recent academic opinion on this subject: http://blogs.ucl.ac.uk/calendars-ancient-medieval-project/2015/07/15/the-etymology-of-sabbath/